# Converting average response times to a summable node-set

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've been running a series of webservice tests in JMeter, and what I'd like to do is take the total sum of the average response times returned by each test. I have a way to find the average response times for each test, but no way to add the averages from the tests together. I am aware that in order to use XPath's sum() function the values need to be a part of a node-set, but from what I understand once I find the average values out of the XML they are no longer part of one. So I need to use the node-set() function, but I am fairly new to XSLT/XPath and am unsure how to get things working.

Any help with this is appreciated!

This is a sample XML from JMeter running with two iterations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../style/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl"?>
<testResults version="1.2">
<httpSample t="78" lt="78" ts="1338826079163" s="true" lb="html" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="4418" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="31" ts="1338826079241" s="true" lb="userRoleRetriever" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="758" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="32" lt="32" ts="1338826079272" s="true" lb="UserActivityWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="2398" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="156" lt="125" ts="1338826079304" s="true" lb="SubscriberMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="56434" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="16" ts="1338826079460" s="true" lb="NetworkMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="33020" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826079507" s="true" lb="AlarmMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="11594" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="141" lt="141" ts="1338826079538" s="true" lb="getSubscribers" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="397" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="265" lt="234" ts="1338826079679" s="true" lb="getMpegResultsById" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="832927" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826079976" s="true" lb="getOverallSummary" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-1" dt="text" by="402" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="0" lt="0" ts="1338826082663" s="true" lb="html" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="4418" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="16" lt="16" ts="1338826082663" s="true" lb="userRoleRetriever" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="758" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="0" ts="1338826082679" s="true" lb="UserActivityWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="2398" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="32" lt="0" ts="1338826082694" s="true" lb="SubscriberMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="56434" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="31" lt="15" ts="1338826082726" s="true" lb="NetworkMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="33020" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="16" lt="16" ts="1338826082757" s="true" lb="AlarmMgmtWSDL" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="11594" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="250" lt="250" ts="1338826082788" s="true" lb="getSubscribers" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="10536" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15454" lt="15392" ts="1338826083038" s="true" lb="getMpegResultsById" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="2023426" ng="1" na="1"/>
<httpSample t="15" lt="15" ts="1338826098555" s="true" lb="getOverallSummary" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="vuserver 1-2" dt="text" by="402" ng="1" na="1"/>

</testResults>
```

This is an exerpt in my XSLT where the averages from each test are found.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[not(@lb = preceding::*/@lb)]">
    ...
    <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(../*[@lb = current()/@lb])" />
    <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(../*[@lb = current()/@lb]/@t)" />
    <xsl:variable name="averageTime" select="$totalTime div $count" />
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

How can I enter these average times into a node-set and subsequently sum them?

[Here is an example of what the final reports look like for those interested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHErb.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT2.0 or just XSLT1.0?

Comment: I believe I can use 2.0.

Comment: Although I am not too familiar with the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use XSLT2.0, then this has built-in functionality to handle node-sets, whereas in XSLT1.0 you would have to make use of an extension function. By means of a node-set, you can just create a variable, which holds a list of (newly created) nodes, and then you can just iterate over them, or even sum them, as if they were the source document itself.

Another thing to note before showing a solution, is that this is also an example of a grouping problem. You are have results for multiple tests, and want to group them by name. The method you are currently using is not necessarily that efficient. In XSLT2.0 though there is the **xsl:for-each-group** function to make things much easier

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample" group-by="@lb">
```

What you just need to do, is created a variable, and build a new node set by grouping the test results, and adding an 'average' node to the new list.

```
  <xsl:variable name="results">
     <xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample" group-by="@lb">
        <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(current-group())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(current-group()/@t)"/>
        <test lb="{current-grouping-key()}" num="{$count}" tot="{$totalTime}" avg="{$totalTime div $count}"/>
     </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Thus, the **results** variable here will contain a list of **test** elements, one for each distinct test, with a newly appended node having the average time. You can then iterate over these results and even sum them.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="/testResults">

      <xsl:variable name="results">
         <xsl:for-each-group select="httpSample" group-by="@lb">
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(current-group())"/>
            <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(current-group()/@t)"/>
            <test lb="{current-grouping-key()}" num="{$count}" tot="{$totalTime}" avg="{$totalTime div $count}"/>
         </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:variable>

      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Total Test</th>
            <th>Total Time</th>
            <th>Average Time</th>
         </tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="$results/test">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@lb"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@num"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@tot"/>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@avg"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="sum($results/test/@num)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="sum($results/test/@tot)"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="sum($results/test/@avg)"/>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to you XML sample, the following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Test</th>
      <th>Total Test</th>
      <th>Total Time</th>
      <th>Average Time</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>html</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>78</td>
      <td>39</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>userRoleRetriever</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>UserActivityWSDL</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>23.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>SubscriberMgmtWSDL</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>188</td>
      <td>94</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>NetworkMgmtWSDL</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>31</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>AlarmMgmtWSDL</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>15.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>getSubscribers</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>391</td>
      <td>195.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>getMpegResultsById</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>15719</td>
      <td>7859.5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>getOverallSummary</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>15</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Total</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>16593</td>
      <td>8296.5</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer, it was very helpful and clear. everything seems to be working perfectly for my report, but I have another question. I need to take two sums of averages for my report, one of them is the total sum of the test averages (which you just demonstrated), the other is the initial sum of the test averages. essentially was that is the sum of the averages times up until a certain test. Is there a way I could modify the XSLT to sum the test averages for every test except test "X" and those after it? e.g. lb="getSubscribers"

Comment: I am sure there is a way! It is probably best you ask a new question, where you can clarify the exact requirements, and I am sure the answer will be soon forthcoming.